# Subversion Edge 5.0.1 upgrade from 4.0.11, services running but 503 error

Tags: windows, upgrade, collabnet, subversion-edge

Upgraded using the downloaded windows installer (64bit) completed without an error. Both Collabnet services are running but I get:

> HTTP ERROR: 503 Problem accessing /csvn. Reason: Service Unavailable.

CSVN console reg entry seems to be pointing to the new Java path `C:\csvn\jre\bin\java.exe`

I'm guessing its a path or config file issue?

Comment: Also getting this issue. Sadly the console breaks on almost every update for me. Very poor quality control. The only non-default thing I ever do is enable HTTPS which you would think is pretty standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more information about this problem on the Collabnet forum. I resolved my issue by uninstalling subversion edge, delete everything in the c:\csvn folder EXCEPT the data folder then re install the application.